# Dell XPS 15 9560. Installed to Corsair Voyager GTX USB-SSD. Stuck at black flashing cursor

Tags: boot, laptop, dell, install

So I booted up ElementaryOS in a VM, and I installed the OS onto the USB as you would install it to a regular SSD/HDD. So I have a portable USB OS. Pretty neat!

Except that it doesn't work after about 3 reboots. It then just boots to a flashing cursor of sorts. I haven't done any updates or anything. It just seems to stop working.

This has happened more than once too. What could be causing the problem?